# display iframes ios using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

Im trying to use an iframe using phonegap for ios, this is the code that I'm using, in android works fine but not in ios, any idea how to display the iframe?

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="70%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in config.xml file?

Also maybe you have to set

```
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView: YES
ExternalHosts: *
```

in Cordova.plist file.

Comment: Well, <access origin="127.0.0.1*" /> isn't the same to <access origin="* " /> : "127.0.0.1*" allows to load all local resources, while "*" allows to load all resources, including external ones, which "google.com" actually is.